# hadoop windows org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin

Tags: windows, maven, hadoop, mojo

I am trying to install hadoop on my windows machine.
I am following this guide: https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows
but when I have to execute this line:

```
mvn package -Pdist,native-win -DskipTests -Dtar
```

I have this error:

```js
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:exec (com
pile-ms-winutils) on project hadoop-common: Command execution failed. Process ex
ited with an error: 1(Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
```

I already read this post [build hadoop 2.2 on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592050/build-hadoop-2-2-on-windows)
but I am not able to understand how to solve.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Alex

Answer (score 3):

You ran that command from a Windows SDK Command Prompt, right? Taking a look at [this guide I wrote recently](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BweVwq32koypYm1QWHNvRTZWTm8/view?usp=sharing) and make sure you have the proper tools installed.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using recent versions of Hadoop, i.e. Hadoop-2.8, or 2.7 then there is no need to built the Hadoop-src using Maven, there is an easy way to configure (higher versions) Hadoop in windows.

[Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) & Install Java in `c:/java/`

> make sure the path is this way, if java is installed in program
>   files, then hadoop-env.cmd will not recognize java path

[Download](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.8.2/hadoop-2.8.2.tar.gz) Hadoop binary distribution.

> I am using binary distribution Hadoop-2.8.1

Set Environment Variables:

```
JAVA_HOME = "c:/Java"
HADOOP_HOME="<your hadoop home>"
Path= "JAVA_HOME/bin"
Path = "HADOOP_HOME/bin"
```

> Hadoop will work on windows if [Hadoop-src](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.8.2/hadoop-2.8.2-src.tar.gz) is built using maven in
>   your windows machine. Building the [Hadoop-src](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.8.2/hadoop-2.8.2-src.tar.gz)(distribution) will
>   create a Hadoop binary distribution, which will work as windows native
>   version.

But if you don't want to do that, then download pre-builted `winutils of Hadoop distribution.`
Here is a [GitHub link](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils), which has winutils of some versions of Hadoop.

> if the version you are using is not in the list, the follow the
>   conventional method for setting up Hadoop on windows - [link](https://dzone.com/articles/build-and-install-hadoop-on-windows-with-native-bi)

If you found your version, then copy paste all content of folder into path: /bin/

> Set all the .xml configuration files - [Link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/single_node_setup.html) & set JAVA_HOME path in hadoop-env.cmd file

From cmd go to:

```
<HADOOP_HOME>/bin/> hdfs namenode -format
<HADOOP_HOME>/sbin> start-all.cmd
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning. The link has my own answer, but still I will post the original answer.

Comment: Ok,  it might not then be deleted from SO. I'm still not sure if copying is the best solution instead consider flagging question as a duplicate to the one you already answered.

Comment: That would probably be a optimistic way to answer the question. Thanks for the pointing out.

Comment: Also when you reach 50 rep you can put the link to answer as a comment if not dare to mark as duplicate.

Comment: Some times questions are not identically similar, but answers match, so I find it a bit unfair to mark it as duplicate or down vote.

Comment: It is true. Therefore commenting should be then considered.

Comment: Actually I did the same, but still I got down vote from you. :D

Comment: It should not matter but it was not from me :)  I prefer to give comments & advice to get this site better.

Comment: Anyways thanks for mentioning. Will improve in next answer.